# Method not Found error when updating SQL Compact db and dbml for linq to sql

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I have a vb.net app that uses linq to sql with a SQL Compact database. I just updated a date field in the database to be nullable and regenerated the dbml using sqlmetal. Now when I run the application, I am getting this runtime error after I click Search button:

Method not found: 'System.Nullable`1 Downtime.Students.get_DateOfBirth()'.

I noticed that the last change I made to a datatype also caused an issue. Maybe I am not updating the dbml file right? It has this method in the .designer.vb file for the dateOfBirth field:

```
<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name:="dateOfBirth", Storage:="_DateOfBirth", DbType:="DateTime")>  _
Public Property DateOfBirth() As System.Nullable(Of Date)
    Get
        Return Me._DateOfBirth
    End Get
    Set
        If (Me._DateOfBirth.Equals(value) = false) Then
            Me.OnDateOfBirthChanging(value)
            Me.SendPropertyChanging
            Me._DateOfBirth = value
            Me.SendPropertyChanged("DateOfBirth")
            Me.OnDateOfBirthChanged
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, sort of: I ended up deleting the dbml file completely, regenerating the dbml using sqlmetal, and adding back into the project.